# Craft Commerce — Update order status from frontend?

Tags: ecommerce, plugin-craftcommerce3, status

Following on from this question [Commerce: How to update an order status via the frontend](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/35897/commerce-how-to-update-an-order-status-via-the-frontend)

We'd like to make it easy for delivery drivers to update the status of a craft commerce order, from a frontend page. Doing it via the CP on mobile is a bit cumbersome as it involves multiple steps.

We've created a user group call couriers.

```
{% extends '_layouts/_logistics' %}

{% block logistics %}
    {% if currentUser and currentUser.isInGroup('courier') %}
        {% include 'logistics/_orders' %}
    {% else %}
        {% redirect 'account' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

In the _orders include we'd like to show a list of orders, each with a 'Mark as Delivered' button, which can be clicked as the orders are fullfilled.

```
<dl>
    {% if order.shippingAddress %}
        {% include 'shop/_includes/addresses/address' with { address: order.shippingAddress } %}
    {% endif %}
    <dt>{{ order.reference }}</dt>
</dl>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="">
    {{ redirectInput('logistics') }}
    {{ csrfInput() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="orderStatusId" value="4">
    <input class="button button--primary" type="submit" value='Mark as Delivered'>
</form>
```

I'm wondering if this can be done, without the need to build a plugin or module? Else is there a plan to include the ability to do this in a future Craft Commerce release.

Many thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels a bit dirty, but you can actually do this directly in a Twig template like this:

```
{% set order = craft.orders.id(123).one() %}
{% do order.setAttributes({orderStatusId: 4}, false) %}
{% do craft.app.getElements().saveElement(order) %}
```

-- naturally you'd need a way to fetch which order you want to update, but you could easily grab that from your POST data or from the URL or localStorage or whatever.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Obviously better to use a controller, however for our purposes this will work. Many thanks for providing a solution.